# Which scientific discipline studies topics?

Tags: terminology

In my understanding, the common understanding of the word "*topic*" is as defined in the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/topic):

> *Subject; theme; a category or general area of interest.*

**Now which discipline deals with this and related effects, for example how to determine topicality of a message in a given context?**

First, I thought it could be linguistics, but this discipline has got their own notion of topic, either they work on a single-sentence level:

> *In linguistics, the topic, or theme, of a sentence is what is being
>   talked about.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sociology could be one consideration. The word “topic” has the ability to shift, what could be considered a “theme” is dynamic, and evolves with societies definition of what it means. Philosophy could also be a major player because you’re concerned with the question of what it means to be a topic, and that sounds like the realm of philosophical thought. To me it sounds more like a question best suited for the social sciences as opposed to the hard sciences.

Answer (score 0):

Linguistics/Natural Language Processing, Machine Learning, and perhaps others.